# Android Studio: app se detiene al iniciar activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, activity

estoy haciendo una app con tres activity, uno de ellos me provoca que se detenga la app, así que he copiado el código en un proyecto nuevo, para ver si "a solas" esta activity funciona... pero no.
El compilador no me detecta errores en el código.

archivo .kt --> Declarar variables

```
private lateinit var etChirpNumber: EditText
private lateinit var btnCalculate: Button
private lateinit var tvResult: TextView
```

Buscar variables y usarlas en setOnClickListener

```
    etChirpNumber = findViewById(R.id.et_number)
    btnCalculate = findViewById(R.id.btn_calculate)
    tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tv_result)
    tvResult.visibility = View.GONE

    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener {
        val chirpNum : Int = etChirpNumber.text.toString().toInt()
        val result : Float = ((chirpNum / 3) + 4).toFloat()
        val sResult = getString(R.string.tv_result, result)
        tvResult.text = sResult
    }
    tvResult.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

}

archivo .xml --> Layout Lineal, no he puesto el código de una imagen y el texto inicial de bienvenida

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_number"
    [...]
    android:hint="@string/et_chirp_number"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_calculate"
    [...]
    android:text="@string/btn_calculate" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_result"
    [...]
    android:text="@string/tv_result" />
```

Es cierto que en archivo de strings, he intentado incluir una parte dependiente (variable)

```
<string name="tv_result">The approximate temperature outside is: %1$s</string>
```

Muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: intenta enviar el parámetro para ese recurso string `text="@{@string/tv_result(``)}"`

Comment: si revisas el logcat? porque por lo menos debería mostrar error en el `setContentView()`

Comment: ¡ERROR ENCONTRADO!
En el archivo strings.xml había escrito $s, cuando realmente lo he cambiado a $f entonces ya me ha salido perfecto.
GRACIAS

Comment: Para que encuentres ràpidamente un problema debes revisar el LogCat y agregar el mensaje de error mostrado en tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Gracias, justo estoy aprendiendo a leer y entender el archivo logcat

Answer (score 0):

Deseas agregar un valor de tipo float cargado a partir de un valor en `Strings.xml`, esto es correcto:

```
    val result : Float = ((chirpNum / 3) + 4).toFloat()
    val sResult = getString(R.string.tv_result, result)
```

El problema es el texto definido en `Strings.xml` indica reemplazar un valor de tipo string:

```
<string name="tv_result">The approximate temperature outside is: %1$s</string>
```

Debes usar `$f` en lugar de `$s`

```
<string name="tv_result">The approximate temperature outside is: %1$f</string>
```

> `$s` : usado para valores de tipo String.
>
> `$d` : usado para valores de tipo decimal.
>
> `$f` : usado para valores de tipo float.

Revisa:

[Dar formato a las strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#dar-formato-a-las-strings)

y

[Android Formatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter)